# Using selenium: How to keep logged in after closing Driver with Twitter

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm exploring web scraping and I use the [php-webdriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) library for scraping.

During my tests, I wanted to keep the user session active even after leaving the navigation. If the user is already logged in on a site A, he should always be logged in during the next session without having to log in again.

Different approaches have been recommended including the one that consists of saving the cookies and restoring it during the next session.

```
<?php
  $serverUrl = 'http://localhost:4444';

  $cookie_file = __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt";

  $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($serverUrl, DesiredCapabilities::chrome());
    
  $driver->get('http://localhost:881/test.php');

  if(file_exists($cookie_file)){
    $cookies = unserialize(file_get_contents($cookie_file));

    $driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();

    foreach($cookies as $cookie)
    {
      $driver->manage()->addCookie($cookie->toArray());
    }

    $driver->navigate()->refresh();
 }
```

If this approach works very well for some sites (I tried with my WP site), I am however curious to understand why it does not work with twitter for example (I tried to log into my Twitter account and keep the session active for the next session).

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work with Twitter? What would it take to make it work?